# Is there any data that prove that D-Aspartic Acid increase testosterone level?

Tags: testosterone

Recently a friend told me about D-Aspartic Acid. Since I was disillusioned about ZMA, I would like to get some knowledge, before I try it out. Are there any scientific studies, that prove it really works? Especially studies not conducted by companies, that sell products containing DAA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A study on the National Institute of Health (NIH) website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2774316/) found an increase in LH and testosterone in both rats and humans.

Some caveats though... This doesn't prove that it will be beneficial as a muscle building aid or supplement. Also, I've seen at least one reference that claimed it also causes the replacement of testosterone with estrogen so that it's not fully effective. I don't have that one handy, so I can't speak to the validity of that claim.

Answer (score 0):

[A study on the National Institute of Health (NIH) website](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4384294/) has shown that it doesn't have any increase in testosterone for active and/or young men